# Unit testing Web API consumer module

Tags: java, api, unit-testing

My code is the consumer of an API (www.abc.com/public/news/apple.json). I get a json array in return which I then parse and populate in my own data structure. the code responsible for doing this is:

```
    public Map<String,List<NewsItem>> populateNewsArray() throws Exception
        {
            url = domain + newsApiStr;
            InputStream stream = getNews(url, true);

           //jackson library object mapper
           ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

          //NewsApiObject class implements the structure of the json array returned.
           List<NewsApiObject> mappedData = mapper.readValue(stream, NewsApiObject.class));

           //populate the properties in a HashMap.
          //return HashMap
     }

     public InputStream getNews(String request, boolean bulk) throws Exception
     {
        URL url = new URL(request); 
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain"); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        connection.connect();

        return connection.getInputStream();
     }
```

As you can see I am not the controller of the api, only the consumer. It is said that in unit tests, one is not suppose to make http requests. In this scenario, how can I unit test the populateNewsArray() function to see if the object mapping was correct (without any exceptions) and a valid hashmap was returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extract `getNews()` into a separate interface, e.g. NewsReader (although the word `Reader` has a specific meaning in the JDK, I like the name...)

```
public interface NewsReader {
    InputStream getNews(String request, boolean bulk) throws Exception
}
```

Then implement that interface with using `HttpURLConnection` as per your code and update your code to allow injection of that particular interface.  Then, if you need to test how your code handles an `InputStream`, you can create a mock of `NewsReader` which returns a `InputStream` with well-known content.

Remember to aim for high cohesion: your class shouldn't be an HTTP client **and** a stream parser.

Comment: btw david, if I do create an interface for news reading, still how can I test the populateNewArray() func? do I need to change the function completely and remove the getNews call so that it can be unit tested?

Comment: @Salmanmahmood `populateNewArray` calls `NewsReader.getNews`.  You can inject a mock which returns a (for example) `ByteArrayInputStream` containing known JSON.

Comment: how will I make sure that the mock object is being called when testing, instead of the real implemetation(which does a network call)?

Comment: Use dependency injection.  You can either do it manually or use a IoC container (Spring / Guice).  The key concept here is that you inject the NewsReader into your class.  For example, define a constructor in your main class that takes a NewsReader instance.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a subclass and overwrite the method `getNews(...)`. In the subclass you then may return an `InputStream` for your test.
Since you should not depenend on some external file in a unit test and in order to get a better testable design I'd also change the `getNews(...)` method to return some kind of value which can be further processed by the mapper.